# C/C++ program to press key every X seconds

Tags: c++, c, time, key

i've got some experience using C/C++ language. 
But i'm playing a game(independent software from mine), and i'd like to make a C program that interacts with the game, to press the key <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> every two seconds. 
It's for windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on the operating system.  windows or linux?

Comment: I suggest you use one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird

Comment: Ok, it's for windows. i understand what you mean josh, but now i need a function to generate an event that simulates i pressed a key from keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the functions `SendInput` and `keybd_event`.  Those are functions that will tell Windows to press a key.

And all you need to do is create a loop that sleeps every 2 seconds.  `keybd_event` is the old convention, but it is the one I'm familiar with.

```
VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  _In_  BYTE bVk,
  _In_  BYTE bScan,
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

The following will simulate the pressing of the <kbd>NumLock</kbd>

```
// Simulate a key press
keybd_event( VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);

// Simulate a key release
keybd_event( VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: keybd_event is way worse than SendMessage().  In all my projects, keybd_event was a pain in comparison.

Comment: I've never had any problems.  I used it one time to allow me to type with a WiiMote, but using the standard window messages is a better way to go.

Comment: keybd_event I think will only work on the foreground window, which might not actually translate well into a game.  I know for websites, keybd_event lacks a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, this is pretty easy.  Make a C++ console program.  Inside your program, you'll need to search all the "windows" in Windows.  Microsoft calls these windows window handles (HWND).  You can search through them all  with FindWindowEx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx.  once you find your window (by name), you can send TO the window HWND keypresses.  This is done with SendMessage(); Put this in a loop every 2 seconds and you're done!

You can find the window you're searching for's properties by using Visual Studio's Spy++.  This will let you easily know what window name to search for.